# SELECT all columns from distinct two columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by, unique, distinct

I need to SELECT * where distinct `'Rua'` with different `'CP'` in the following DB:

```
id      Rua                  Local           Conc       CP
81143   dos moinhos          Rio Tinto       Gondomar   0123
81142   dos Moinhos          Rio Tinto       Gondomar   4435
81141   dos Moinhos          Rio Tinto       Gondomar   4435
```

With the following query, i am able to obtain the two columns:

```
SELECT Rua, CP 
FROM  Codigo
GROUP BY Rua, CP
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

But i want all the columns. `SELECT *` returns *"Column 'Codigo.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."*

So i came upon this answer: [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns)

I didn't go for the accepted answer, as i need a fast query (*this will be used for AJAX search suggestions*). I used the other highly upvoted answer. So, i created the following query:

```
SELECT * From Codigo
WHERE  (Rua,CP) IN (
   SELECT Rua, CP
   FROM   Codigo
   GROUP  BY Rua, CP
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 
);
```

That returns *An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','* error. Why it expects `Rua` after `WHERE` to be boolean? In the answer they used `saleprice` which don't seem boolean.

So my question is how can i select **all** columns **including** the rows with same `Rua` and `CP`, but those only once (`DISTINCT`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does not support `(a,b) in (val1,val2)` syntax

Use `EXISTS` to check the pair

```
SELECT *
FROM   Codigo C1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   Codigo C2
               WHERE  C1.Rua = C2.Rua
                      AND C1.CP = C2.CP
               HAVING Count(*) = 1);
```

or use `COUNT() Over()` Window aggregate function to count the records for each `Rua, CP` combination and filter the group which is having count as `1` to find one `Rua` row per each different `CP`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Count(1)OVER(partition BY Rua, CP) AS cnt
        FROM   Codigo C1) A
WHERE  cnt = 1
```

This will be my preferred approach since it is much efficient than using `EXISTS` the optimizer has to scan/seek the table only once

If you don't want duplicate records then use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_Number()OVER(partition BY Rua, CP Order by id) AS RN
        FROM   Codigo C1) A
WHERE  RN = 1
```

I have ordered the duplicate records using `Id` column and picked the first record out of duplicates.

Comment: Both work. The first suggestion takes 33 seconds, the seconds takes 3 :) Why such a difference?

Comment: @Dillinger - Because the optimizer has to scan/seek the table only once in second approach

Comment: I guess i didn't present the question correctly. I want the rows with same `Rua` and `CP` to be included too, but just once. With this, i only get results that don't have repeated `Rua` and `CP`. If i edit and fix my question, will you fix your answer?

Comment: @Dillinger - Yeah sure.

Answer (score 2):

Using Window Function (Single table read):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
  (SELECT t.*, COUNT(1) OVER (partition BY Rua, CP) AS cnt FROM Codigo t
  ) t
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

Using EXISTS (Reads the table twice):

```
SELECT *
FROM Codigo t1
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM Codigo t2
  WHERE t1.Rua    = t2.Rua
  AND t1.CP       = t2.CP
  GROUP BY Rua, CP 
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  );
```

JOIN (Twice again):

```
SELECT C1.*
FROM Codigo C1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Rua, CP FROM Codigo C2 GROUP BY Rua, CP HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  ) C2
ON C1.Rua = C2.Rua
AND C1.CP = C2.CP;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` in `Exists` method is not needed